# Aws Elasticbean doesn't run my .jar application

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, jar, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, procfile

After upload and deploy on aws, the .jar file hadn't started. So the static contents are being served, and nginx is being reconfigured (by custom configs) but the jar file (Which was in root of .zip I've uploaded) was not run after deployment so I had to run it via ssh command, and of course it shuts down after closing ssh terminal...
I included procfile as defined on amazon site but no progress..

Comment: If there is an error with the deployment process you should be able to find something in the server logs indicating what the issue is.

Comment: There's no issue on deployment, it all passes green, plus no logs are indicating any errors.. Is there any more documentation about Procfile?

Comment: If you want an example of an Java App using Procfile, the latest version of beanstalker ships with one. Use $ mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=elasticbeanstalk-javase-archetype to find it

Comment: How is it going? I also got your problem today. Not only there's nothing in `/var/log/web-1.log` and `/var/log/web-1.error.log`, but also nothing in `/var/log/supervisord.log` ! :(

Answer (score 2):

Let me see if I understood: You are having problems having your java code running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk because it thinks your code is ok by probing the static index.html file for instance, right?

In this case, there are two things to look for:

- Set a [Health Check URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html) pointing to one of your java endpoints. In particular, it is useful if you could diagnose each and every external dependency (other AWS Services, databases)
- Log on to the instance - ensure you can get all the logging you can: Environment Variables, System Properties - that would be a start

Hope it helps